# Oracle Self Join and linking with another table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have a puzzle when self joining a table. I just can't seem to work it out.

For example I have a table Employee with all employee records. I have a temporary table with two fields, Employee ID 1 and Employee ID 2. This temporary table stores the relation between two employees. (It's in a temporary table because it regularly gets updated).

Now I want to display both employees information in one row as output. I am able to self join, but when it comes to linking with the temporary table I get confused.

Employee Table:

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name  Status    Joined_Date
111     Jack      On_Leave  01/01/2000
222     Smith     Working   02/02/2000
333     Joan      Working   03/03/2001
444     Emily     On_Leave  04/04/2001
555     Mark      Working   05/05/2002
```

Temporary Table:

```
Emp_ID_1   Emp_ID_2
111        222
222        555
```

Now the output I'm trying to get is:

```
Emp_ID_1 Emp_Name_1 Status_1  Joined_date_1 Emp_ID_2 Emp_Name_2 Status_2 Joined_date_2
111      Jack       On_Leave  01/01/2000    222      Smith      Working  02/02/2000
222      Smith      Working   02/02/2000    555      Mark       Working  05/05/2001
```

This is a simplified example as my actual Employee table has many additional columns to display for both Employees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-joining is nothing magical. You're joining two tables, which just happen to be the same table, so you absolutely have to use table aliases to distinguish between them. In your case:

```
SELECT e1.*, e2.*
FROM   employee e1
JOIN   temp_table t ON e1.emp_id = t.emp_id_1
JOIN   employee e2 ON t.emp_id_2 = e2.emp_id
```

Comment: I feel a bit silly now for making it over complicated. Thank you for the solution!